# ADFS authentication is not passed to a webmethod in an application page in the _layouts

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, adfs, webmethod

I recently configured a sharepoint 2013 farm to use ADFS and converted the web application successfully, every thing is working fine except one thing, in my portal i have multiple webparts that communicate to webmethods (GET,POST) using Ajax jquery calls, these webmethods are hosted in an application page which resides in the _layouts.

my farm has 2 web front end, now the problem that **sometimes** these webmethods cannot see the logged in user so spcontext.current.web.currentuser is null.

and i noticed that sometimes i notice multiple logins even though i am already logged in and i have changed the servicetokenexpirationwindow to 4 days!

the session state is configured in the farm and enabled in the web application.

our azure load balancer is configured to keep the client ip to stick with the same machine.

Please help me!

Comment: When CurrentUser == null, you may need to add this line of code: 

Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.HandleAccessDenied(new UnauthorizedAccessException());

Comment: Have you checked this thread?https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/98e14e7a-2621-48f7-94b7-2c9be4f9606a/get-current-logged-in-user-in-provider-hosted-app?forum=appsforsharepoint